# How to become a biostatistician?

Tags: biostatistics

What should a graduate student (MS in biostat) to be prepared to become a biostatistician?

I've learn some statistics. But what I do now is just like statistician. I am just wondering what I should do to be a biostatistician? Thank you.

Comment: What's "bio stay"? ... do you mean "biology, say"?  ... in that case the obvious thing would be to learn more statistics.

Comment: You already have a MS in biostatistics & you are asking what a biostatistician is? Are you asking what the difference is between "statistics" & "biostatistics"?

Comment: @gung obviously a paper of certification of your degree of MS or PhD or whatever doesn't mean you are an expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A biostatistician is basically a statistician who is a content matter expert for a particular field which happens to be in the health sciences, usually biomedical but also public health, epidemiology, etc. Entry level (non senior) positions are not necessarily expected to be so well prepared, but it is a good interviewing question to ask what familiarity level is expected and/or how they might support you, e.g. conferences, journal subscriptions, training courses, etc.

Other than that, you will like so many other statisticians spend most of your time working with data in spreadsheets, formatting and cleaning, and occasionally running regression models.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your answer. As a junior specialist for two months, what I am doing currently is just like what you wrote at second paragraph, though I've learnt a lot indeed even from this. Following you suggestion, I think what I should do is to read more paper and see how does a biostatistician play his role in the whole experiment design, not only statistical analysis part.

Comment: @FrankFan I guess you should feel confident that you have a good eye for quality in all aspects of the research conduct, and can lean in to assist your collaborator wherever it is necessary.